# Reading contents from a stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I was testing how to read data out of an `std::streamstring` but I'm getting it wrong, could anyone point out what's the problem? and give a correct way to read it?

My testing code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 16

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Un texto con datos de ejemplo para probar la extacción de un stream";

    std::cout << "Stream contents: '" << ss.str() << "'" << std::endl;

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    std::streamsize read = 0;

    do {
        read = ss.readsome(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
        std::cout << "Read: " << ss.gcount() << std::endl;
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
        std::fill(buffer, buffer + BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    } while ( read > 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting the output:

```
Stream contents: 'Un texto con datos de ejemplo para probar la extacci¾n de un stream'
Read: 15
Un texto con da
---
Read: 15
tos de ejemplo
---
Read: 15
para probar la
---
Read: 15
extacci¾n de un
---
Read: 5
 stre
---
Read: 0

---
```

As you may notice the last read operation reads only 5 characters leaving out the last two 'am' even though it should have been able to read it. Am I missing somtehing?

Comment: I think you need to work with `wchar_t` version of streams and strings.

Comment: Replacing the `ó` with a regular `o` result in the same result. Why would I need to work with `wchar_t` anyway?

Comment: I copied your code into a .cpp file and compiled using g++ with no arguments.  On my machine, the entire stream gets printed with no truncation, but the first read only grabs one character.  I'm using gcc 4.9.2, and glibc 2.21-3.

Comment: So you are able to read it all... I'm using visual studio 2008. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Regarding the comment from @BarryGackle, you can see it for your self [here](http://ideone.com/UU7ZhI). Might be a bug in the VS2008 (which *is* quite old now) standard library.

Comment: Could be that a bug is present in one compiler and not the other.  Could also be a bug in the code that, for whatever reason, happens to manifest itself differently on different compilers/machines (like you'd expect a buffer overflow to do).  I'm leaning towards the first of those, since several people seem to have looked at your code and none of us has seen any obvious issues with it.  You definitely aren't doing anything obviously wrong, though, or we'd all see the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `readsome` does only read the immediately [available characters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome)  and what that is depends on the platform, so it is well allowed to return 0 while there are still characters in the stream and a subsequent call could probably return the missing characters. 
To get all available data, I'd rather use `read` in combination with `gcount` to get the Number of characters you read.

```
do {
    ss.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
    read=ss.gcount();   
    std::cout << "Read: " << ss.gcount() << std::endl;
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    std::fill(buffer, buffer + BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
} while ( read > 0 );
```

Just for clarification:
While I believe, the behavoir you observed is allowed by the standard, I don't see why the implementation should behave like this when the input stream is based on a string literal (im not familiar with the implementation details of streams). What you could check is, if `read` actually corresponds to `rdbuf()->in_avail()` and if it doesn't this might indeed be a compiler bug.

Comment: Making that change solve the problem. So `readsome` should be used in a pooling manner? (since may return 0 event though there is content left).

Comment: @Javier Mr: I don't really know. As Far as I can tell, the Idea behind readsome is to give you all characters that are available without a potentially blocking systemcall. So I'm not sure If you'll get all the data at all. On the other hand I also don't understand, why the specific implementation of VC++2008 would not give you all the data from a local string object. If you are talking about thread pools however, I'd definitely say no as it is not threadsafe, so you would have to serialize it anyway.

Comment: yea I meant single threaded consecutive calls. I understand the aim of `readsome` to block as little as possible. However I tested changing the do-while condition to `!ss.eof()` and apparently `readsome` never reads the whole stream, also checked the `in_avail` and starts with a value of 50 and in each call decreases without ever reading the last ones. Thanks.